# how to resize any image to a given width and height in php?

Tags: php, image, resize, image-resizing

i want to resize any image with same width and height like width 156px and height 156px. Visit this link http://djcorner.ae/ and you will see all products images are of same size. Help me out please.

Comment: You could use an image resizing library, however it would be a lot easier to resize it using CSS. However you'll only resize it visually, the size of the image won't change, so it may cause some bandwidth use, depending on the size of the image.

Comment: i tried many libraries like phpthumb etc but they didn't exactly resize image that i want

Comment: http://libgd.github.io/   the gd library.  You can check the original image size and conditionally resize it, it's capable of almost any thumbnailing task.  It's slow...resize once and save the thumbnail like a cache, don't resize every load on demand.